# Push/Add multiple JSON objects one by one to the API using ajax and for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm working on a code where I can push a `JSON` objects one by one inside an array going to the API using `AJAX` and `for loop`. The code here is just a rough sample of what I have been working on. I can't seem to make it work on in pushing the objects to the `API JSON array`

```
var lms_json    = <?php echo json_encode($json_data); ?>;
var jobjects = JSON.parse(lms_json);
var data = jobjects[0];

for ( i = 0; i < jobjects.length; i++ ) {
    var data = jobjects[i];


    $.ajax({
          type     : 'POST',
          url      : url,
          data     : data,
          dataType : 'json',
          success  : function() {
              console.log(success);
          },
          error    : function(error) {
              console.log('Error')
          }

    })



}
```

Comment: Can you please tell what error you are getting?

Comment: Where are you posting your data? Why not pass the whole JSON object or JSON string into your ajax call, and do the processing server-side?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSON.stringify to serialize your JSON object. Also, specify the content-type to make the server expect JSON data. This might work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: callback
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that AJAX is asynchronous process so you can do the following to do it correctly:

```
var lms_json    = <?php echo json_encode($json_data); ?>;
var jobjects = JSON.parse(lms_json);
var i=0;
function makeAjax(url, objs){
   var data = objs[i];
   i++;
   $.ajax({
      type     : 'POST',
      url      : url,
      data     : data,
      dataType : 'json',
      success  : function() {
          console.log(success);
          makeAjax();
      },
      error    : function(error) {
          console.log('Error')
      }

   })
}
makeAjax(url,jobjects);
```

So After every success callback run it will run the next. so it will be synchronous process.

I hope it helps.